# How to disable touchpad acceleration in Gnome (Wayland)

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad, wayland, libinput

I'm trying to disable the touchpad mouse acceleration on Ubuntu 21.04, with Gnome 3 using Wayland. The settings have no option for it, Gnome Tweaks has nothing and I was unable to find a setting using dconf editor.

As far I have understood, a way to do this would be editing the hwdb entry, but I have not figured out how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated!